# Cannot initialize model with custom CombiTable1D without instance of Modelica CombiTable1D

Tags: modelica, dymola

My objective is to create a 1D/2D lookup table that can read a variable sized array in JSON file without having to specify a statically sized Modelica array parameter.

I started out by trying to extend ExternData to implement a custom table based on a suggestion in a github issue: https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExternData/issues/34#issuecomment-718552210

The steps outlined were:

> - Create your own copy of a CombiTable, modify it to accept a data access object and a stable name, see code snippet below
> - Create a duplicate of the ExternalCombiTable1D, which instead references your own CombiTable data object
> - Create a c-function which reads the data directly from the json and stores it into a table object, which is then passed to the MSL
>   function ModelicaStandardTables_CombiTable1D_init2

I've implemented all three steps to make a custom CombiTable1D block which populates a dynamic sized table from ExternData JSON functions. Package code below:

https://github.com/vsskanth/ExternData.CustomTable

In this package, there are 3 experiments of relevance to this issue. All experiments compile but only only one experiment works:

- `ExternData.Examples.JSONTestVariableArrayBroken.mo` - Single instance of custom CombiTable1D - does not initialize
- `ExternData.Examples.JSONTestArrayCombi2DBroken.mo` - Custom CombiTable1D and instance of Modelica CombiTable2D - does not initialize
- `ExternData.Examples.JSONTestVariableArrayWorking.mo` - Custom CombiTable1D and a couple instances of Modelica CombiTable1D  - works as expected

I am trying to find out why my custom CombiTable1D implementation initializes and runs only when there is at least one instance of Modelica CombiTable1D present in the experiment. I made sure to link `ModelicaStandardTables.h` and `ModelicaStandardTables.lib` libraries in my own implementation, checked for warnings in `dsbuild.txt` and compilation seems to be fine.

For some reason, the constructor function for the custom ExternalCombiTable1D external object (`ExternData.Types.ExternalCombiTable1D`) does not return and hence the custom CombiTable1D block (`ExternData.Tables.CombiTable1D`) is not able to initialize when there are no instances of Modelica CombiTable1D tables in the model.

I would appreciate any thoughts on why this is happening and how to overcome it.

- IDE - Dymola 2021x
- OS - Windows 10
- Compiler - Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Did your workaround become obsolete by https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExternData/issues/34#issuecomment-789265840, that is, by updated library https://github.com/tbeu/ModelicaTableAdditions?

Comment: @tbeu Yes this makes this problem obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tbeu has been generous enough to add JSON support to
https://github.com/tbeu/ModelicaTableAdditions which renders this issue moot since I can just use that package with ExternData.

Its still interesting as to why this happens though. Seems like a Dymola translation bug.